# Google Plus icons on the 10k tools migration stats

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, 10k-tools

This is how the 10k tools currently looks like on Physics, more specifically the [migration tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last30days).

> [image]

Are those Google Plus icons intentional? 'cause I smell a bug =).

---

The googley icons persist if I log in on an incognito chrome window, and they were also observed by a P.SE moderator.

If I go in to inspect, I get that the responsible element is

```
 <span class="migrated from"></span>
```

whose background image is set to http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/physics/img/sprites.png?v=6f2a56ff0bac:

> [image]

I'm not sure what this thing is, or how the css manages to pick out just the google plus icon from there, or indeed what sort of html black magic is going on here, but if a designer sees this I imagine they'll be able to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: They're the correct arrows on Software Engineering. Do you have any extensions that could be messing with the images?

Comment: @ChrisF A fair amount, but the icons persist if I re-visit from incognito.

Comment: I have the correct arrows on Stack Overflow also, have you tried inspecting the element?

Comment: The sprite on physics looks wrong. Where the `<` arrow would be there's that `g+` icon. One of the designers should take a look at what's going on there.

Comment: @Oded but the sprites were re-created as SVG, e.g. [here on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.svg?v=bb0497e70aa3). Maybe someone just forgot to update the URL in the stylesheet? ([SVG version](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/physics/img/sprites.svg) exists for physics, but without the social share buttons. Weird)

Comment: @Sha the PNG version is a fallback for browsers that don't support svg.

Comment: @Oded so those with browsers that do support SVG won't see the google icon at all? Is this on purpose?

Comment: Not what I am saying, just that the SVG has a PNG copy (should be pretty identical). Why they are different, is the issue here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked [Stéphane](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245505/st%C3%A9phane) to fix the sprite - it is now deployed and all is well.

Comment: I can confirm it on my end. I do (idly!) wonder what happened there - did G+ lean on a designer to provide some sneaky advertising? ;-P

Comment: The sprite has changed over years, those were originally there, but removed to a different sprite sheet over time. Guess this one file didn't transition for some reason (humans involved... so yeah...).

Comment: 376 rep vs. 125k - why didn't you let him answer? ;)

Comment: He had his chance, @Sha - you snooze, you lose.